# AWS Appsync Javascript query example and input syntax

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm using Amplify and Appsync for a react app I'm building. Right now I'm trying to query a user and am using the appsync client:

```
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
  url: awsconfig.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
  region: awsconfig.aws_appsync_region,
  auth: {
    type: awsconfig.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
    jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken()
  },
  complexObjectsCredentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials()
});
```

I've been able to successfully run a mutation using the example provided on the amplify website

```
const result = await client.mutate({
    mutation: gql(createTodo),
    variables: {
      input: {
        name: 'Use AppSync',
        description: 'Realtime and Offline',
      }
    }
  });
```

but when it comes to running a query using the client, the only example they provide is with a list operation

```
const result = await client.query({
    query: gql(listTodos)
  });
```

They don't provide an example for how to query by a specific ID, so I'm wondering if anybody can shine some light on the syntax for this, provide an example, or point me in the direction of a good reference for this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not much different from mutation example, kindly see the code below:

```
const getBlog = `query GetBlog($id: ID!) {
  getBlog(id: $id) {
    id
    title
    content
    author
  }
}
`;
```

Run a Query with parameter

```
   const result = await client.query({
        query: gql(getBlog),
        variables: { id: '0002b432-157a-4b6a-ad67-6a8693e331d1' }
             });
      console.log(result.data.getBlog);
```

Or

```
  const input = { id: '0002b432-157a-4b6a-ad67-6a8693e331d1' }
      const result = await client.query({
              query: gql(getBlog),
              variables: input
                                   });
      console.log(result.data.getBlog);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was unsure the format of the variables parameter.